# Haguichi fails to configure with an error (Ubuntu 14.10)

Tags: software-installation, vpn

First time installing and running haguichi. After clicking <kbd>configure</kbd> I get this error:

```
Failed to get D-Bus connection: No connection to service manager.
```

See: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Hamachi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to install a hidden dependency (who knows why the deb file doesn't do this) and THEN reinstall the deb.

```
sudo apt-get install lsb
```

THEN

```
xdg-open ~/Downloads/<hamachi>.deb
```